# Buttons in pyqt4 end up having the same event handler even though they shouldn't

Tags: python, pyqt4

The commands array contains a list of tuples each one containing a name and the function that will handle the event. For each pair a new button is created and added to a QListWidget. 
The problem is that all the buttons end up calling the same handler function. The last one in the list. I have checked with my debugger and it does loop correctly through the list and the correct handler function is passed on each loop.

This is the function generating the buttons.

```
def load_commands(self):
    for name, handler in commands:
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton(name)
        btn.clicked.connect(lambda: handler(self))
        item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
        item.setSizeHint(Qt.QSize(0, 30))
        self.list_commads.addItem(item)
        self.list_commads.setItemWidget(item, btn)
```

[EDIT] Just in tried setting btn and item to None at the end of each loop. It did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to each handler, otherwise only last one will be left in scope. One way to do that is with a default argument:

```
    btn.clicked.connect(lambda *args, handler=handler: handler(self))
```

Note that `clicked` always sends the checked-state of the button, so `*args` is there to avoid clobbering the default argument.